# How to remove an event listener with querySelectorAll after the click event is registered?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I'm trying to build a game where a user will select one of the 6 divs displayed to him. Here I want to perform two operations, first is to get the index of the div that was clicked so I can perform some operation on the selected div. Secondly, I want to remove the event listeners on all those initial 6 divs.

I'm very new to JS and I'm stuck. Moreover, if you can give me a better approach I will be grateful.

here is the Code Snippet

```
function listenForSelection(target){
    let attributeArr = document.querySelectorAll(`.power-container-p${target}`);
    for(let i = 0; i < attributeArr.length; i++){
        attributeArr[i].addEventListener('click', judge.bind(null , i, target, attributeArr));
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < attributeArr.length; i++){
        attributeArr[i].removeEventListener('click', judge);
    }

}
```

here is the judge function that wants the index of the clicked div to perform its action.

```
var judge = function(i, target, attributeArr){
    let opposite = (target == 1) ? 2 : 1;
    let attribute = "";
    switch (i){
        case 0:
            attribute = "Age";
            break;
        case 1: 
            attribute = "Power";
            break;
        case 2:
            attribute = "Strength";
            break;
        case 3:
            attribute = "Defence";
            break;
        case 4:
            attribute = "Morality";
            break;
        case 5: 
            attribute = "Average";
            break;
    }

    console.log(attribute);
    console.log(target); 
    
}
```

Comment: you'd have to save a reference to `judge.bind(null , i, target, attributeArr)`

Comment: @JaromandaX can you please show me how to do that? From what I know the Judge function is already a named function so this like **attributeArr[i].removeEventListener('click', judge);** should have worked.

Comment: `let x = judge.bind(null , i, target, attributeArr)` ... but then you use x in add and remove ... of course, your code snippet makes zero sense since it looks like you want to add then remove straight away ... no click is going to happen in that brief moment

Comment: @JaromandaX If I perform the remove operation once the click has been registered, that will solve the problem, right? Like including the remove loop inside the judge function.